# Execute an action when a button is pressed with Zend without opening a new page

Tags: php, zend-framework, button

I develop with Zend.
Is it possible in a form when the submit button is pressed, to execute a specific action of a specific controller , rather than opening a web page.
current version:

```
<form action=<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'translation',
'action'=>'traduction'));?>><input type="submit" value="es"/>
```

what I want:

```
<form action=<?php
//Execute the action TRADUCTION of the TRASLATION controller and stay in this page ?>>
input type="submit" value="es"/>
```

I hope I'm clear

Comment: @AmitGarg and how to specify the controller of this action

Comment: You can directly use `action="controller_name/Action_name"`

Comment: @AmitGarg I tried this <form action="translation/traduction"..
but it renders me to a new page (traduction.phtm), and this is my problem

Comment: Whatever You are doing on translation/traduction you can do that on your current controller.

Comment: I put in the traduction action a function that applicate the traduction to the language selected in the buttom, so the new langage will be applicated to all pages. And I put the traduction function in a seperated controller beacuse the user can, from any page, select a langage, so I can't put the traduction function in each page, that's whe I should have a seperated translation controller

Comment: You should use a model if you have to use it on multiple controllers.

Comment: Can you please explicate more? Because I just begin to use zend? Thanks for advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax for performing the action:

```
<form id='frm'>
<input type="submit" value="es"/>
```

And make ajax call as:(using jquery in this case)

```
<script>
$('#frm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post({
        url:<?php echo this->url(array('controller'=>'translation','action'=>'traduction'));?>,
        data:$('#frm').serialize(),
        success:function(){
             //done
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Note: this code uses jquery, so you also have to load jquery.js.

Comment: Place it in a script tag in your template file. Also, if you are not using jquery, load jquery.js before the code. Note: the core idea is using ajax, you can implement it anyway you want.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to avoid page reloads is using javascript asynchronously.

[basic tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/)